# Calcular diferença entre datas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou aprendendo Javascript e estou fazendo uma calculadora de aposentadoria. Gostaria de saber como pegar as duas datas inseridas no formulário html e calcular a diferença entre elas e dar como saída a diferença.

Tenho o seguinte html

```
<form name="aposentadoria">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Sexo</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" /><i class="fa fa-male"></i>Masculino:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F" /><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Feminino<br />
</fieldset>

<select name="regra">
    <option value="25">25 anos</option>
    <option value="20">20 anos</option>
    <option value="15">15 anos</option>
</select>

<label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
    <input type="text" name="empresa" placeholder="Empresa: ">

<label for="dataAdm">Admissão</label>
    <input type="date" name="dataAdmissao" placeholder="Admissão: ">

<label for="dataDem">Demissão</label>
    <input type="date" name="dataDemissao" placeholder="Demissão: ">
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcula()" >
```

E o JavaScript

```
function calcula(){
var sexo = document.aposentadoria.sexo.value;
var regra = document.aposentadoria.regra.value;
var empresa = document.aposentadoria.empresa.value;
var dataAdmissao = document.aposentadoria.dataAdmissao.value;
var dataDemissao = document.aposentadoria.dataDemissao.value;
var anosAjus = "Você trabalhou " + "anos nas empresas " +empresa+ " sob a regra de " +regra;

alert(anosAjus);
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar com esse cálculo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de converter esses valores dos input num objeto data e depois compará-las. Como me parece que só queres comparar os anos, [podes fazer assim](https://jsfiddle.net/5odbz3o2/):

```
var dataAdmissao = new Date(document.aposentadoria.dataAdmissao.value);
var dataDemissao = new Date(document.aposentadoria.dataDemissao.value);
var anosAjus = dataDemissao.getFullYear() - dataAdmissao.getFullYear();
```

Dependendo do nível de detalhe que precises podes ter em consideração se a data de inicio é fim do serviço completam 12 meses entre elas para contar ou não o ultimo ano, contar com as férias etc. Também podes usar simplesmente timestamp (milisegundos) e procurar a diferença entre as duas datas assim: `anosAjus / 86400000 / 365` que é uma aproximação grosseira sem ter em conta os anos bissextos.